# Save output raster and automatically open in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.6

I want to reclass (by Table) raster files, then perform raster addition of the output (reclassed) rasters, then automatically display the final output (raster SUM) in ArcMap. This is the code that I created. Lines 1-32 works well, but when I add line 33

This error will appear:

> "______, line 33, in  SUM.save(SUM) TypeError: type 
>   is not supported"

```py
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import os.path

# Set environment settings
path = "mypath"
env.workspace = path.replace("\\","/")

#To overwrite existing files
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Local variables:
F1 = "raster1"
F2 = "raster"
TABLE = "F.dbf" #Table to reclass raster
F1_REC = "raster1_reclass"
F2_REC = "raster2_reclas"
SUM = "sum.tif"

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Reclass by Table F1
arcpy.gp.ReclassByTable_sa(F1, TABLE, "F1_FROM", "F1_TO", "F2_RE", F1_REC, "DATA")

# Reclass by Table F2
arcpy.gp.ReclassByTable_sa(F2, TABLE, "F2_FROM", "F2_TO", "F2_RE", F2_REC, "DATA")

# Process: Add F1_REC and F2_REC
SUM = Raster(F1_REC) + Raster(F2_REC)
SUM.save(SUM)
```

Comment: What happens when the code is run? How is that different from your expectations? What is your question? Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: You should probably break this into two separate questions:  1.  How do I save an output raster?  2.  How do I open a saved raster in ArcMap from Python?  They are completely separate issues, and questions here should be about a single concise issue.

Comment: You're overwriting your `SUM = "sum.tif"` string variable with `SUM = Raster(F1_REC) + Raster(F2_REC)` and then trying to pass your `SUM` Raster object to `SUM.save()` which is expecting a string.  Use something like `sum_raster = Raster(F1_REC) + Raster(F2_REC)` and `sum_raster.save(SUM)`
S

Answer (score 1):

You have asked two separate questions.  I will attempt to answer the second question, which I think is:

**How do I use Python to open a saved raster in an ArcMap document?**

A Python script like the following should do it:

```
import arcpy, os

rasterPath = "C:/some/path/to/a/raster"
mapFileTemplatePath = "C:/some/template/folder/blank_map_file.mxd"
newMapFilePath = "C:/some/other/folder/new_map_file.mxd"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mapFileTemplatePath)  #  Load the existing map document from disk (but not in ArcMap)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]  #  Get the first data frame in the map document
rasterLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(rasterPath)  #  Create a mapping layer from the raster path
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, rasterLayer)  #  Add the layer to the map document

mxd.saveACopy(newMapFilePath)  #  Save the map document
os.startfile(newMapFilePath)  #  Tell the operating system to open the map document - if it has a .mxd extension, it should open in ArcMap by default
```

arcpy cannot create a new MXD from scratch, so you always have to start with an existing MXD.  Therefore it is useful to have a blank (or otherwise suitably populated/configured) MXD file in a known location ready for this task.

This is all done with the `arcpy.mapping` module.  See:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/analyze/arcpy-mapping/introduction-to-arcpy-mapping.htm

Related to your other question (about saving a raster), your script has an error as already mentioned by others in comments.

You should change this:

`SUM = "sum.tif"`

to this:

`rasterFile = "sum.tif"`

AND change this:

`SUM.save(SUM)`

to this:

`SUM.save(rasterFile)`

Otherwise is makes no sense to use 'SUM' as a variable name for two different values.  Which ever you assign to it second will override (and effectively delete) whatever you assigned to it previously.  This change should resolve the error that was added to your question afterwards.